# Recognizing route with regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, postback

Let's say that I have a postback url that comes in as

```
http://domain/merkin_postback.cgi?id=987654321&new=25&total=1000&uid=3040&oid=123
```

and other times as:

```
http://domain/merkin_postback.php?id=987654321&new=25&total=1000&uid=3040&oid=123
```

If my route definition is

```
map.purchase '/merkin_postback', :controller => 'credit_purchases', :action => 'create'
```

it barks that either of the two forms above is invalid.

Should I be using regex to recognize either of the two forms?

Comment: I don't think that you can call the :create action in this manner, due to Rails conventions (not positive, but I seem to remember having issues doing that a few years ago).  Try creating a new action with a different name to use.  Also, I think that .php and .cgi may not work well with the routing.  I would change the routes to domain/merkin_postback/:id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a routing issue, it's a content format issue. You should be using `respond_to`.

```
class CreditPurchasesController < ActionController::Base
  # This is a list of all possible formats this controller might expect
  # We need php and cgi, and I'm guesses html for your other methods
  respond_to :html, :php, :cgi

  def create
    # ...
    # Do some stuff
    # ...

    # This is how you can decide what to render based on the format
    respond_to do |format|
      # This means if the format is php or cgi, then do the render
      format.any(:php, :cgi) { render :something }

      # Note that if you only have one format for a particular render action, you can do:
      #   format.php { render :something }
      # The "format.any" is only for multiple formats rendering the exact same thing, like your case
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But heed @james_schorr's note -- you may not be able to map onto `create` this way, probably a good idea to choose a different action.